# After installing Ubuntu, computer becomes stuck on HP logo during boot

Tags: boot, hp

I am using an HP Pavilion 20 All-In-One

I used a USB to install Ubuntu and went through the basic start-up options. I selected to finish installing Ubuntu while erasing everything else on my computer. After Ubuntu finished installing I was given a message saying that I needed to restart my computer for everything to go into effect. Now everytime I restart my computer it gets stuck on the HP logo and refuses to boot.

**Things I've Already Tried**
- Unplugged the computer and held down the power button for 15 seconds
- Ran a DPS Self-Test and received a completion code of 0
- Tried booting from the USB again

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've tried nearly every solution I can find online.

Comment: Likely the machine isn't setup to boot from the right device or the Ubuntu installer didn't install its entry correctly in UEFI if UEFI is used. Go to the BIOS settings and verify the right drive is selected to be booted from. If that doesn't do it, again in the BIOS, turn off any EFI/UEFI boot and switch it to legacy where legacy can be called something like "Legacy", "CSM", "BIOS". There isn't a standard naming for the old boot process. Also turn off any Secure Boot stuff you see. Once you've done that change, reinstall Ubuntu again.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to test is if the hang is a GUI-loading issue or actual boot issue.

When it hangs press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and see if you get the black console login page. If you can login via text mode, but still have the hang on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then I have the same issue and have a workaround:

- On boot, select "Advanced options for Ubuntu".
- Next select the line that has "(recovery mode)"
- Then select "resume boot"

If that works then it's probably a `modeset` issue in Grub.

[This tutorial](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842) has some thing to try.

What worked for me was adding `nomodeset` to the Grub Linux boot options.

Edit: `nomodeset` interferes with power suspend if you have an AMDGPU. Went back to not using `nomodeset` and instead using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, logging in with a text screen and then running `startx`.